# Expose C++ public headers (that contain listeners) in Swift

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, listener

I have an static library coded in C++, also I have some headers to let users of the library to create instances of these classes.

I created the bridge file when I create some Objective-C wrappers to use the library and these are exposed fine in the "swift side".

My problem is that I also have C++ classes that are listeners consumed by the C++ library (these have pure virtual methods). I would like to have these Listeners classes (or protocols) available in Swift (forcing the user to implement the methods that are pure virtual) and pass them to the C++ library.

For example I have the class that consumes the Listeners:

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_EXECUTOR_H
#define FUNCTION_EXECUTOR_H

#include "ResultListener.h"

namespace test {

    class FunctionExecutor {

        public:

            // Method that consumes the listener
            void setListener(ResultListener* listener);

        private:

            ResultListener* _listener;

    };

}

#endif
```

And the listener:

```
#ifndef RESULT_LISTENER_H
#define RESULT_LISTENER_H

namespace test {

    class ResultListener  {

        public:

            virtual void listenResult(int result) = 0;

    };

}

#endif
```

Is it there an efective way to expose the "Listener" class and let users to create implementations of that class with swift forcing the use of the pure virtual method?

Comment: Do you understand that you can't write C++ classes on Swift?

Comment: But you can write with Objective-C++ C++  class, that conform to `ResultListener` and takes Objective-C class as delegate and you can write on Swift Objective-C classes. Got the point?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I understand that I cannot write C++ code on Swift, that is why I'm trying to implement this in the best way.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I understand that I cannot write C++ code on Swift, that is why I'm trying to implement this in the best way. If I understand correctly your second comment then I need to create these classes: C++ class with the implementation of the Listener, also an Objective-C  wrapper class that will be the one that can be used in the swift side with the same methods from the C++ interface. So in the Swift side I could create a sub class of the wrapper and redefine the implementation of the method (with Swift) and pass it to the wrapper that consumes the listener, am I understanding well? Thanks!